# Is it possible to use my HSA for a payment I've already made?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hsa

I misplaced my HSA debit card, and while waiting for a new one was forced to pay a qualified health care expense out of pocket. Is there any way to use my HSA to cover the expense retroactively?

Comment: Depending on the amount and whether you can afford the out-of-pocket payment, you should consider whether you want to be reimbursed or are happy to leave that money in the account to grow tax-free.  See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/treat-hsa-as-an-ira?rq=1

Comment: I've done this, but it required an itemized receipt from the hospital, which I had to request specially.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas , that depends completely on your HSA provider. Mine allows me to reimburse myself any amount of money I feel like, without questions asked. At the end, this is between me and the IRS.

Comment: @Aganju - Yep, that turned out to be true in my case. I just transfer the money out, and they include that disbursement on my 1099-SA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can be reimbursed through your HSA account; see for example [NerdWallet's article](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/pay-medical-expenses-credit-card-hsafsa/).  Best is to see your own provider's website, of course, but HSA rules in general allow for reimbursement for legitimate medical expenses.

Comment: Since my HSA provider is my credit union this turned out to be as simple as transferring funds from my HSA to my checking account and dealing with the paperwork come tax time.

Answer (score 7):

The HSA websites I have used have had several options.

1. **Card receipt** - Submit a receipt to verify a card transaction.
2. **Pay my provider**. -Request payment to be mailed directly to your provider.
3. **Pay me back**. - Request payment to reimburse you for out-of-pocket expenses (receipt required).
4. **Pay me**. -Request a withdrawal from your HSA (no receipt required).

You are asking about #3 or #4. It is a pain to send the receipt for #3 but if you do, you know that they will list it as being used for a medical reason when they send you the 1099 at the end of the year.

Comment: From my understanding you can even pay yourself back for a larger expense over time, if you don't have enough in the HSA now (you can keep taking amounts out as you and/or your employer contribute to it).

Answer (score 3):

My HSA allowed me to order a checkbook for $10. I have written checks to myself for HSA-eligible expenses that were not charged to the HSA.